# Field name is not know when I have two optional data sources

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have formula in my report file that have some optional field.

This is my formula

```
if {viewtbl.ProductID}="2" then    
   "This Product must be send at " ToText(CDate({viewtbl.DateSend}), "dd-MM-yyyy") 
else   
   "This is not Product 2"
```

In my aspx.vb file, I also have two optional data sources depend on what product that selected in drop down list.

```
If ddlProduct.SelectedValue = "2" Then
  Me.DataSource = "Select t1.ProdName, t2.DateSend from tbl1 t1 iner join tbl2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID"
Else
  Me.DataSource = "Select ProdName from tbl1"
End If
```

So, when the selected drop down is product 2, the report is fine. But I we select other product, the report getting an error because `{viewtbl.DateSend}` is not known.

I've tried to make two separate formulas but still getting the same error.

How can `{viewtbl.DateSend}` is not known when formula and the data source is not directly point to Product 2 ?

And also how can I solve this because it seems taht I can't make two separate report for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply every field used in report, even if it is never evaluated.

Try setting `Me.DataSource = "Select ProdName, NULL AS DateSend from tbl1"` if selected product is not 2.